# I am using below code but while executing it, I am getting an error as " Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg()" I have updated my php.ini

Tags: php

```
<?php 

class Image
{

    public function generate_filename($length)
    {

        $array = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');
        $text = "";

        for($x = 0; $x < $length; $x++)
        {

            $random = rand(0,61);
            $text .= $array[$random];
        }

        return $text;
    }

    public function crop_image($original_file_name,$cropped_file_name,$max_width,$max_height)
    {

        if(file_exists($original_file_name))
        {
 
            $original_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($original_file_name);

            $original_width = imagesx($original_image);
            $original_height = imagesy($original_image);

            if($original_height > $original_width)
            {
                //make width equal to max width;
                $ratio = $max_width / $original_width;

                $new_width = $max_width;
                $new_height = $original_height * $ratio;

            }else
            {

                //make width equal to max width;
                $ratio = $max_height / $original_height;

                $new_height = $max_height;
                $new_width = $original_width * $ratio;
            }
        }

        //adjust incase max width and height are different
        if($max_width != $max_height)
        {

            if($max_height > $max_width)
            {

                if($max_height > $new_height)
                {
                    $adjustment = ($max_height / $new_height);
                }else
                {
                    $adjustment = ($new_height / $max_height);
                }

                $new_width = $new_width * $adjustment;
                $new_height = $new_height * $adjustment;
            }else
            {

                if($max_width > $new_width)
                {
                    $adjustment = ($max_width / $new_width);
                }else
                {
                    $adjustment = ($new_width / $max_width);
                }

                $new_width = $new_width * $adjustment;
                $new_height = $new_height * $adjustment;
            }
        }

        $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
        imagecopyresampled($new_image, $original_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $original_width, $original_height);

        imagedestroy($original_image);

        if($max_width != $max_height)
        {

            if($max_width > $max_height)
            {

                $diff = ($new_height - $max_height);
                if($diff < 0){
                    $diff = $diff * -1;
                }
                $y = round($diff / 2);
                $x = 0;
            }else
            {

                $diff = ($new_width - $max_height);
                if($diff < 0){
                    $diff = $diff * -1;
                }
                $x = round($diff / 2);
                $y = 0;
            }
        }else
        {
            if($new_height > $new_width)
            {

                $diff = ($new_height - $new_width);
                $y = round($diff / 2);
                $x = 0;
            }else
            {

                $diff = ($new_width - $new_height);
                $x = round($diff / 2);
                $y = 0;
            }
        }

        $new_cropped_image = imagecreatetruecolor($max_width, $max_height);
        imagecopyresampled($new_cropped_image, $new_image, 0, 0, $x, $y, $max_width, $max_height, $max_width, $max_height);
        
        imagedestroy($new_image);

        imagejpeg($new_cropped_image,$cropped_file_name,90);
        imagedestroy($new_cropped_image);
    }
```

Comment: All my images are jpg, I presume this should not be a problem though.

Comment: There are several other questions about this error message. Have you read them and tried to use those solutions? It means there's a problem with the way the GD library is installed in your PHP.

Comment: Hi Barmar, thank you for reply, based on the answer on several other questions, I have mentioned that I have updated the php.ini file as this is what mentioned in most of the answers unless I am missing something. Thanks

Comment: Did you restart apache after updating php.ini?

Comment: Yes, I did and not even once but multiple times :)

Comment: Are you sure you've updated the correct `php.ini` file? There may be multiple versions, for Apache, CLI and FPM, for example. And if you have different PHP versions, this all gets multiplied.

Comment: Hi Greg, when we are talking about different version, is it like all these versions are through the same server? I am using Xampp for apache. Is there a way I can look what ll versions are there?

Comment: Call `phpinfo()`, it will tell you what php.ini was actually used in the top section.

Comment: Thanks for all your time. This issue is solved but now I am facing another issue which might related to the same thing but not sure. Below is the error: